# How to delete all text after last - found in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, substring

I wanted to remove last two sections of string. So e.g. I have string "SLS Hotel -23-true" I wanted to remove -23-true from string. I cant use SUBSTRING_INDEX("SLS Hotel -23-true",'-', 1) as it will return me first text but for some text I do have "1 - Up -23-true" so wanted a solution for remove last found with -

I wanted to do it quickly from MySQL database please let me know if there is any quick fix or else I have to traverse through Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one replaces from the second last -
so it'll give you `SLS Hotel` and `1 - Up`

```
SELECT REPLACE("SLS Hotel -23-true",CONCAT(" -",SUBSTRING_INDEX("SLS Hotel -23-true",'-',-2)),"");
```